# AngularJS: Background process

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app and I would like to add a background process that runs without any view. All it is doing is regularly call a webservice and do something about it, no UI.

A quick and dirty way is to simply put the code in window.onLoad. But should I be thinking of doing this the angular way? If so, do I put the code in a Service? How would I "start" this service initially?

Comment: Depends on what this background task does. It can be service too, you can start in in usual run phase.

Comment: @dfsq This background task calls a webservice using $http in a regular interval, that's it. Could you elaborate "usual run phase"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered it yourself, service is the right choice, you can inject it in any controller you have on app, if that's not the case and you have no controller (or directive) then you can do it in `angular.run`

```
angular.module('lookMaMyModule').run(function(injectables){
  do something fancy on run
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I think `run` might exactly be what I'm looking for. I do have controllers but I don't want to tie this service to any of them because they are unrelated. Any of the controllers could disappear one day but this background task will remain. Reading up on angular.run now...

Comment: I'm usually trying to avoid that for various reasons but in my work big project we run several services in `.run` mostly initialising services that wont be used by controllers or directives but live on their own like a singleton factory or service

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple concept for you, it might have small problems, but you will get the idea.

```
angular.bootstrap2 = function(module, element, callback){
    angular.bootstrap(module, element);
    callback();
}
```

remove ng-app tag from html, and bootstrap app

If background process is ng module, then use `angular.module('name').run();` else use self bootstraping technique

#### app.js

```
angular.module('name', ['deps']);
angular.bootstrap2(['name'], document.body, function(){
    var process_1 = new MyServ();
    process_1.start();
});
```

#### service.js

```
var MyServ = function(){
    this.intervalId = 0;
    this.start = function(){
        this.intervalId = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('executing');
        }, 1000);
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        setInterval.cancel(this.intervalId); //don't remember api, sorry :<
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
app.run()
```

this gets called when the angular app is starting

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module